Prove that the dual of a LCA group is a topological group
I consider $G$ a LCA group and $\hat{G} = Hom(G, S)$ its Pontryagin dual so that the set $Hom(G, S)$ is composed of continuous homomorphism. I would like to show that endowed with the compact-open topology,  $\hat{G}$ is a topological group, that is the mapping $(\chi_1,\chi_2)\mapsto \chi_1\chi_2^{-1}$ is continuous.
For this, I would like to use the very definition of continuity, but I am stuck at some point. Let me try to elaborate this :
Let $(\chi_1,\chi_2)\in\hat{G}\times\hat{G}$ and $W$ be a neighborhood of $\chi_3 = \chi_1\chi_2^{-1}$ in $\hat{G}$. We know that there exists an open set $O\subset W$ such that $O = \cup_{I\in I}\cap_{j\in J_i}O(K_j, U_j)$ (with $\lvert J_i\rvert <\infty$ for all $J_i$) where $O(K,U)=\{f\in C(G, S) : f(K)\subset U\}$ where $K$ is a compact subset of $G$ and $U$ an open set of $S$. This implies that there exists $i\in I$ such that for all $j\in J_i$ we have $x_3\in O(K_j, U_j)$, that is $\chi_3(g)=\chi_1(g)\chi_2^{-1}(g)\in U_j$ for all $g\in K_j$, $j\in J_i$.
I would like to define a neighborhood of $\hat{G}\times\hat{G}$ of the form $V = V_1\times V_2$ where $V_1 = \cap_{j\in J_i}O(K_j, U_j)$ and $V_2 = \cap_{j\in J_i}O(K_j, {1})$ but ${1}$ is clearly not open in $S$.
I would like to know if you have any hint to give please ?

I tried something and I would like to have your advice please. For this, we use the fact that $S$ is a topical group under multiplication and with the topology induced by $\mathbb{C}$.
For all $j\in J_i$, we have $\chi_3(K_j)\subset U_j$ where $U_j$ is an open set of $S$. Fix $g_j\in K_j$ define the map $\tau_{\chi_3(g_j)}(g)=g\chi_3(g_j)^{—1}$, we know that it is an homeomorphism in $S$, hence the set $\tau_{\chi_3(g_j)}(U_j)$ is an open set in $S$ that contains the neutral element $1$ so that there exists $V_j$ an open set in $S$ that satisfies $V_jV_j\subset\tau_{\chi_3(g_j)}(U_j)$ and so $\tau_{\chi_3(g_j)}^{-1}(V_jV_j) = \tau_{\chi_3(g_j)^{-1}}(V_jV_j)\subset U_j$. But $\tau_{\chi_3(g_j)^{-1}}(V_jV_j) = V_jV_j\chi_3(g_j)$. So if we have two characters $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ in $\hat{G}$ such that $\psi_1(K_j)\subset V_j$ and $\psi_2(K_j)\subset V_{j}^{-1}\chi_3(g_j)^{—1}$ we have that:
$$
\forall g\in K_j,\quad \psi_1(g)\psi_2^{—1}(g)\in V_jV_j\chi_3(g_j)\subset U_j
$$
Hence, if we define $V_1 = \cap_{j\in J_i}O(K_j, V_j)$ and $V_2 = \cap_{j\in J_i}O(K_j, V_{j}^{-1}\chi_3(g_j)^{—1})$ , hence for all $(\psi_1,\psi_2)\in V = V_1\times V_2$ we have $\psi_1\psi_2^{-1}\in\cap_{j\in J_i}O(K_j,U_j)\subset W$
Not correct : $(\chi_1,\chi_2)$ seems to not be in $V$
